# C++ pipe process not terminating

Tags: process, pipe

I made a program that takes two commands typed in by the user and pipes the first into the second. It works fine if real commands are entered but I'm having a problem getting my error check to work when I just enter random words. In most places of my code where I use exit() the process terminates fine but within the two child processes rs1 and rs2, I cannot exit. I'm new to processes so I'm not sure how to do this correctly. Can someone help?

```
int main()
{
while(true)
{
    int argc1=0,argc2=0,rs1,rs2,pipefd[2];
    char input1[80],input2[80],*argv1[6],*argv2[6],*p1,*p2;
//*Big block of code that receives input goes here*
    pipe(pipefd);
    rs1=fork();
    rs2=fork();
    if(rs1==0)
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        rs1=execvp(argv1[0],argv1);
        if(rs1==-1)
        {
            perror(argv1[0]);
            exit(rs1); //Here is where I'm having the problem
        }
    }
    if(rs2==0)
    {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        close(0);
        dup(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        rs2=execvp(argv2[0],argv2);
        if(rs2==-1)
        {
            perror(argv2[0]);
            exit(rs2); //Here also does not work correctly
        }
    }
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    wait(&rs1);
    wait(&rs2);
}
return 0;
}
```